# pressing a uiview makes a grey background swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uistackview

I have a button inside a stack view inside a content view inside a tableview cell. when pressing anywhere in the cell I get a weird behaviour - 
a grey background and button become disabled. I tried making the cell or the stack or the content views content to be disabled, but then I can't press the button. 
any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default table view row selection. By default, the table view rows, when selected, turn gray. If you want to disable this selection and only want the buttons to be selectable, try disabling selection on the table view as follows:

`tableView.allowsSelection = false`